# Why did Director Krennic personally go to the data vaults?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

During the Battle of Scarif, Jyn and Cassian are in the data vaults and dozens of Stormtroopers are killed trying to make their way in to stop them. Then Director Krennic decides to personally go down there to stop them. I can't understand why he did this personally given that:

- He seems to be in charge in the war room and thus by leaving is neglecting important duties as a leader
- He is not nearly as well armed, armored, or trained as the dozens of Stormtroopers who just died trying to get in

So why did he personally go down to the data vaults?

Comment: Krennic doesn't seem to trust anyone. His inferiors are incompetent, and people like Tarkin are trying to steal his projects from him. In a galaxy of hologram communication, he travels to Mustafar to talk to the scariest cyborg in the Empire, in person. I guess you'd call it micro-managing, he just can't seem to give orders without being there himself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were two reasons, covered in Freed's official novelization (Chapter 20):

1. He saw this as personal. He was focused on Galen already. And he realized Galen's daughter was against him now.

   > KRENNIC TRIED TO FOCUS ON Galen Erso’s communications archive. ...
   >   **Galen had set this in motion**. If he had reached out to allies in the Rebellion, sent the traitorous pilot to contact those allies on Jedha, summoned those allies to Eadu, arranged for them to hound Krennic even after Galen was rotting in a mudhole of a mass grave…
   >   **Krennic stopped short. He remembered now, on the Eadu platform—a flash of dark hair and a face covered in ashes. He recalled the voice saying: You’ll never win. But it was Lyra who spoke, not Galen**.
   >   “—unauthorized access at the data vault.”
   >
   > Krennic shut out the man’s nattering. The rebels were inside the Citadel. They were inside the vault. They were determined to steal the schematics, to find an imaginary weakness, no matter how many lives they lost. **They were determined to haunt him on Galen’s behalf.**
2. He saw General Ramda as unable to deal with the problem, and there were too many unlikely wins for Rebellion already, so he adopted "If you want it done right, do it yourself" stance.

   > **And Ramda wasn’t up to the task**. The shield gate was shut and escape was surely impossible; yet too many impossibilities had already occurred for one day.
   >   He hurled his words behind him as he marched toward the stairs. “Send my guard squadron to the battle! Two men with me!” There was someone in his way; he roughly shoved the body to one side, not bothering to identify the man’s face. “And get that beach under control!”

   (and earlier, his opinion of Ramda:)

   > General Ramda was a fool, and Krennic had already decided to have him tried and imprisoned for gross incompetence.

Comment: Was General Ramda one of the Stormtroopers who went down there? I'm not understanding his connection to this that would make an officer decide to go down there.

Comment: @Thunderforge - he was in charge of Krennic's military. And, to Krennic, incompetent and this not capable of dealing with whoever infilttrated the data vaults. He felt he needed to take the mission himself, and only needed two stormtroopers to back him up.

Comment: Does the novelization say anything about his combat training? Was it somehow superior to the average Stormtrooper? I'm having a hard time grasping that an officer whose duty is to command and not fight on the front lines would think he could kill the intruders singlehandedly when dozens of Stormtroopers already died trying.

Comment: @Thunderforge - it did (that's a material for another question :) But he had no idea who was in the vault, just intruders

Answer (score 5):

Krennic's fatal flaw is that he believes himself to be a man of action, an equal to luminaries such as Tarkin. When something goes horribly wrong, he seeks to put himself at the centre of the action, believing that his *personal* involvement will somehow rectify the situation.

Like many (most?) middle-management technocrats who think themselves worthy of the top job, he lacks the ability to effectively delegate in a crisis when any fool could have spotted that the attack on the beach was a diversion.

> *“Send my guard squadron to the battle!” The death troopers would help
> break the back of the rebel assault, but **Krennic had to hit the heart
> of the problem himself. “Two men with me! Get that beach under
> control!”***
>
> *Krennic shoved his way out of the room, leaving others to worry about
> the rest of the battle. **If he wanted whatever was going on in the data
> vault stopped, he would have to put an end to it himself.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story – A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Tarkin, by comparison sees to the heart of the problem within seconds and takes ruthlessly decisive action.